# Why my php array is over written when they have same Keys

Tags: php

I have a custom PHP function which executes a stored procedure and returns an array:

```
function test(){
  $in      = array("abc","bcd","efg");
  $result  = mydba->executestoredprocedure('proc1',$in);
  $arr_sim = array();

  foreach ($result['recordset'] as $rows) {
    if (!empty($rows)) {
      echo $arr_sim[$rows['field1']] = $rows['field2'];
    }
  }

  return $arr_sim;
}
```

In the above function `$arr_sim` is returning the number of items correctly when the `rows["field1"]` values are different. If the `rows["field1"]` values are the same then it is overwriting the first value and returning only the last one. How can I overcome this?

```
array ( [chicago] => 'sears', [rochester] => 'liberty' )
```

If the `$arr_sim` contains these items then it is returned correctly. Because the keys are different.

```
array ( [chicago] => 'MCD', [chicago] => 'TACOBELL' )
```

If the `$arr_sim` contains these items then it is not returned correctly. Because the keys are the same, "chicago".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array keys must be unique. Instead, do something like this:

```
// You want the array to look like this
// array('chicago' => array('MCD', 'TACOBELL'));

function test(){
  $in  = array("abc","bcd","efg");
  $result = mydba->executestoredprocedure('proc1',$in);
 $arr_sim=array();
 foreach ($result['recordset'] as $rows) {
  if(!empty($rows)){
    if(array_key_exists($rows['field1'], $arr_sim) {
        $arr_sim[$rows['field1']][] = $rows['field2'];
    } else {
        $arr_sim[$rows['field1']] = array($rows['field2']);
    }
  }
 }
 return $arr_sim;
}
```

Comment: @Karim79:I need the keys even which are repeatating  and as well as  unique .How can i rewrite my above Function

Comment: @Someone - I've rewritten your function.

Comment: @karim79:would this return both the Unique keys and as well as repeatating keys

Comment: @Someone - each 'key' will associate with an array. So, 'chicago' for example will contain an array of two elements, 'MDC' and 'TACOBELL'.

Comment: @karim:When I call this function Do i need Declare Double Dimensional Array or single Dimensional Array .How can i consume this array .Earlier i used to say like this" $arr_print['city_name'] = test("data");"

Comment: $arr_print['city_name'][0], $arr_print['city_name'][1], etc. so `foreach($arr_print['city_name'] as $cityName) { echo $cityName };` if I get you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$arr_sim[$rows['field1']] = $rows['field2']` with `$arr_sim[$rows['field1']][] = $rows['field2']`. This will create an array of arrays.

```
echo $arr_sim['chicago'][0]; // MCD
echo $arr_sim['chicago'][1]; // TACOBELL
```

Technically, you should write something like this to avoid notices:

```
if (!isset($arr_sim[$rows['field1']])) $arr_sim[$rows['field1']] = array();
$arr_sim[$rows['field1']][] = $rows['field2'];
```

But you must really ask yourself, is the `field1` (city names) worthy of being the primary key for the array? If not, you should choose some other identifier.